# Exporting current frame from the Movie Clip Editor

Tags: python, texturing, keyframes, texture-painting

I'm making some **Camera Projection mapping** in Blender.

The issue I have is that when I Paint my projections using the clone method (with multiple UV maps from view). It's working great except that I can't seem to be able to use video in the **"Clone from image"** function.

So my question is how can one export still frames from the Movie Clip Editor?

Is there a builtin function or should it be scripted?

Comment: Might be interesting: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=s_MXkTP73CI&index=15&list=PLa1F2ddGya__tVlgy0KNkF4ns8sNUF-2N  All the scripts, you possibly find here: https://github.com/sebastian-k/scripts